# How to Navigate XML where all tags include attributes

Tags: xml, regex, perl, xpath

My XML looks like this:

```
<Servers type="Container">
<Server type="Category">
    <HostName type="Property">dmitri-spB</HostName>
    <HostIPAddress type="Property">14.341.516.564</HostIPAddress>
```

In *most* cases within this data, I don't need the attributes--or at least I have only seen one case in the data where I might need it. In any case...IF the XML looked like this:

```
<Servers>
<Server>
    <HostName>dmitri-spB</HostName>
    <HostIPAddress>14.341.516.564</HostIPAddress>
```

...I would do something like:

```
    my $parser = XML::LibXML -> new();
    my $tree = $parser -> parse_file ($source_dir."\\".$xmlfiles);
    for my $Servers ($tree->findnodes ('/Servers')) {
        foreach my $Server ($Servers->findnodes('./Server')) {
            $hostname = $Server->findvalue('HostName');
            $hostIP = $Server->findvalue('HostIPAddress');
        }
    }
```

I tried to use this same approach by using the entire tag literally in the code, and got an "XPath error: Invalid expression".

So, there are really two problems--how do I navigate and extract when I DON'T care about the attribute, and how do I do it when the attribute is significant? Maybe this is an XPath question, but I simply can't relate XPath documentation to what I'm trying to do. Suggestions?

Comment: what XPath expression gave you "XPath error: Invalid expression" ?

Comment: did you try to run the example code you're showing above? It may very well work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the attributes altogether. They are not part of the *"entire tag"* as you imagine, but additional information on each element.

So use your code as it is and it should work.

To select elements by values of their attribute you can use the XPath `@` notation in a predicate. So, for example, to find all `Server` elements with a `type` attribute of `Category` you can write  `Server[type = "Category"]`.

You can create a parser object and process the source data in one go using `my $document = XML::LibXML->load_data(location => 'myfile')`. `location` allows you to pass a file name or a URL, and you can also specify `string` and pass a simple Perl string containing the XML, or `IO` and pass a file handle open for reading.

There is also no need to iterate over each step of the path in a separate loop. For instance, you can process all `Server` nodes with a `type` attribute of `Category` like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => "$source_dir/$xmlfiles");

for my $server ($doc->findnodes('/Servers/Server[@type = "Category"]')) {
  print ref $server, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Yes. If I include the '@' notation in each element of the XPath path, this works well. I have not had success without it, but that's fine. I have used your tip regarding getting back all nodes and explicitly looping through them. The explicit loop is clearer to me because of my limited abilities, but your method forces me to think more about what is actually being returned and how I'm accessing the content--so that's a good exercise for my brain. You've removed my roadblock, and it's working as I need it to.

Comment: Above, I meant to write '*rather* than explicitly looping', not *and* explicitly looping. I must have had some other tiny error that I've corrected, because as you guys suggested, the code works just fine now, with or without the '@' predicate. All is well.

Comment: @KirkFleming: Th problem with writing two loops as you did is that the outer loop is looping over just *one* `Servers` element and so is executed only once. The existence of a loop incorrectly implies that there are several nodes to iterate over.